# No such file or directory - git ls-files -- WINDOWS

Tags: ruby, git, github, rake, rubymine

I am trying to find a way to add Git to the Windows path. Whenever I try to run RakeFiles from either JetBrains' neat IDE, RubyMine or from GitBash itself, I get the error that this title is posted under:

```
 No such file or directory - git ls-files
```

According to a fellow developer, I need to add Git to my windows path. I haven't been able to find how to remedy this error for anything BUT Macs. Is there anyone who can help me figure out how to fix this with Windows?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Right-click "My computer" and choose Properties
2. Click Advanced system settings
3. Click on Environment Variables, under System Variables, find `PATH`, and add the directory where `git.exe` is located. Directories are separated with semicolons.

The funny thing is, that this simple operation is very uncomfortable, especially when your `PATH` is long and [people created tools, only to edit system path](http://www.redfernplace.com/software-projects/patheditor/).

Comment: Rafal, you just made my day. If you're ever in Cleveland, I'll buy you a coffee.

Comment: You're welcome! Currently I'm in Poland, but I will keep it in my mind :)

Comment: So. Weirdly, I had the same issue on my home computer. I tried to put in the same fix that you suggested, and somehow am getting the "No such file or directory - git ls-files" that I was earlier. :/

Comment: Looks like I just had to close and re-open GitBash in order to get it to work.

Comment: I've always wanted to write "Have you tried turning it off and on again?" on SO.

Comment: Well. You didn't get to do it before I did. But still... Mission Accomplished?

Comment: Alternatively write
`set PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin%PATH%;` or `set PATH=C:\PROGRA~2\Git\bin;%PATH%;` just before you run your `gem install bundler` and `bundle install`.

it will be effective for the current CMD session (until you will close the console).

if you would like to edit your PATH through the registry, add it to:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` / `Path` (will be effective after logout and login your account).

cheers!