# No such file or directory - git ls-files

Tags: git, bundler, rubymine

So. I know I've [asked this before with a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793806/no-such-file-or-directory-git-ls-files-windows) regarding this. But it seems that after I've solved the issue with attempting to `bundle update` in GitBash by adding the Git load path to Windows' environmental variables, I seem to now run into the same issue with RubyMine and trying to run a `bundle update`.

Long story short, I try to run a `bundle install` or `bundle update` with "gemspec" in my Gemfile and I run into this error:

> No such file or directory - git ls-files

Answer (score 2):

Change the path to one without spaces. (i.e. "Program Files" causes problems when using bundler, at least for me it did, in Windows).

Sorry I can't post comments on your question, otherwise I would have posted that there.