# Octopress blog deploying error 'rake aborted! No such file or directory - git remote -v'

Tags: windows, git, github, github-pages, octopress

I installed octopress on my windows(windows8 x64) successfully, then I created a repo named **wenliangcan.github.com** and tried to deploy a blog on github.

When I type the command `rake setup_github_pages` and enter the *repository url*,it gives me an error:

```
rake aborted!
No such file or directory - git remote -v
```

Before entering the *repository url*,it gives me an example like this:

```
Enter the read/write url for your repository
(For example, 'git@github.com:your_username/your_username.github.com)
```

While some third-party tutorial's example like this form:

```
git@github.com:your_username/your_username.github.com.git
```

I had tried both of them,but it gives me the same error.

Here's the screenshot of CMD:

[image]

The content of the screenshot:

```
D:\Profiles\GitHub\Octopress>rake setup_github_pages
Enter the read/write url for your repository
(For example, 'git@github.com:your_username/your_username.github.com)
Repository url: git@github.com:wenLiangcan/wenliangcan.github.com.git
rake aborted!
No such file or directory - git remote -v

Tasks: TOP => setup_github_pages
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

D:\Profiles\GitHub\Octopress>rake setup_github_pages
Enter the read/write url for your repository
(For example, 'git@github.com:your_username/your_username.github.com)
Repository url: git@github.com:wenLiangcan/wenliangcan.github.com
rake aborted!
No such file or directory - git remote -v

Tasks: TOP => setup_github_pages
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

How could I solve this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 No such file or directory - git remote -v
```

That would mean your ruby script doesn't find git in the current execution `PATH` (a bit like in [this issue](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/1838)), or the rake script somehow force set its own PATH.
So make sure the PATH is correct when launching rake command: see "[No such file or directory - `git ls-files` — WINDOWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793806/no-such-file-or-directory-git-ls-files-windows)" as an concrete illustration.

the other issue could be a ruby version issue (1.9.2 working, 1.9.3 not working) on Window7 (see "[Installation on Windows 7 - segmentation fault when running "rake db:migrate"](https://www.chiliproject.org/boards/1/topics/913)")

Comment: Thank you! I added the directory of `git.exe` to `PATH` and now everything is OK : )