# Bundle install fails - Gem using github url - What is wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my gemfile I have:

```
 gem 'capistrano-cook', github: "subsis/capistrano-cook"
```

Here is the error log when running `bundle install` in the ruby/rails console: http://pastie.org/private/aftbq3rukjdthua4lfjzbw

```
C:\rails\app>bundle install
Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler
troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/capistrano-cook-d0d4f904a443/capistr
ano-cook.gemspec:17:in ``': No such file or directory - git ls-files (Errno::ENO
```

In Git Bash console when running bundle install it works fine. But when requiring the gem in the capistrano deploy file it is not loaded. Seems like it is not installed after all.

The bundler gem is version 1.2.3

```
C:\rails\app>gem show capistrano-cook
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    Unknown command show

C:\rails\app>bundle show capistrano-cook
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/capistrano-cook-d0d4f904a443

C:\rails\app>
```

Comment: Add your git.exe directory to $PATH.  See this post for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793806/no-such-file-or-directory-git-ls-files-windows

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
gem 'capistrano-cook', :git => 'git://github.com/subsis/capistrano-cook.git'
```

Comment: Have you installed `git`? Check `c:\>git -v`.

Comment: I have gem install git. Git is not aviable in the rails/ruby console. So git -v wont work..I have git installed. Git bash.

Comment: How should it be installed? I have Git bash installed and I have run `gem install git` in ruby/rails console.

Comment: [It's not as hard as it seems...](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git)

Comment: Cool, [here it is](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git#Installing-on-Windows).

Comment: I have installed git. Still the bundle fails in ruby/rails console.

Comment: I think [here is the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793806/no-such-file-or-directory-git-ls-files-windows), good luck.

Comment: My path is set to : `C:\Ruby193\bin` how do I add git to this path? Git is located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe` semicolon got it,.

Comment: Ok I have added git to the path: `C:\Ruby193\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe` But still get the error in ruby console.. and I cannot say git -v