# Git bash why are gems not installed?

Tags: ruby, git

I am using Windows 7 and have git installed. In the Git Bash console I have ruby available.

When I run `bundle install` in Git bash the gems installed are not added to the gem list. It seems like the gems are not installed after-all.

If I run `bundle list` I can see the gem, however. Is this because the paths are different?

Why are the gems not installed and added to gem list?

Comment: What is wrong with my question?

Comment: I think, somebody didn't understand your question and downvoted. 

Maybe the ruby script you are using are not compatible with mingw or cygwin (depending which version of git bash you have installed)

Comment: It seems like the gem is added to bundle list.. I don´t understand why  I cannot use git url in ruby console. When bundler says it is possible: http://gembundler.com/

Comment: How do I find the git path? So I can indlude it in the ruby console..

Comment: `echo $PATH` or you can use `env | grep PATH`. The path in Windows is set in the same way as you do for the command line. to set the path in git you need to edit `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` and add a line like `export PATH=/path/to/whatever:$PATH`. In unix `:` is used as path separator. You can change the path in Windows, and it will be inherited by git bash: http://superuser.com/questions/76219/changing-path-windows-7-without-restarting

Comment: I have looked on the path. But I cannot find git? Is it named mingw?

Comment: run `which git` at the terminal to see where the `git` command is located, and you'll find where the git command is. You need some basic bash tutorial (and maybe read more on how mingw emulates unix filesystem on windows)

Comment: I have added it know. When I run bundle install. It says it is using the gem. Bundle list the gem appear. But not on gem list..

Comment: I have updated the issue.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913423/bundle-install-fails-gem-using-github-url-what-is-wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run `bundle install` in a normal command window

Comment: If I run it in the normal command windows. rails/ruby console I get this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913423/bundle-install-fails-gem-using-github-url-what-is-wrong

Comment: Is rails installed properly?  try typing `rails -v` in your cmd window.  Also, git is a totally separate issue.  I would focus on one at a time.

Comment: Yes, it is installed..I just have to install this gem, with a github url..

Comment: Posted this on your other question also: Add your git.exe directory to $PATH.  See this post for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793806/no-such-file-or-directory-git-ls-files-windows

Comment: If the gem only have a .gemspec? How do I then create the .gem?

Comment: you have a lot of questions :)  There are some tutorials for that online, I recommend http://railscasts.com/episodes/245-new-gem-with-bundler

Comment: Ok, I needed to build the gem to create the .gem file and install it.. Finally!