# how do I get past this error in bundle install

Tags: ruby, rubygems

getting this error when trying bundle install on my windows 10 machine
There was an error while loading `wax_theme.gemspec`: No such file or directory - git ls-files -z. Bundler cannot continue.

any help appreciated!

the file wax_theme.gemspec is right there in wax-main so at a loss

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No such file or directory - git ls-files -- WINDOWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793806/no-such-file-or-directory-git-ls-files-windows)